# problems with exporting function with babel and nodejs

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using babeljs with webstorm.
The arguments to babel are:

> --source-maps --out-file $FileNameWithoutExtension$-compiled.js $FilePath$

I have the following es6 code:

```
export function primeFactors(num) {

    let res = [];
    let n = 2;
    while (num > 1) {
        while(num%n ===0) {
            res.push(n);
        }
        n++;

    }
    return res;
}
```

it gets transpiled to

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.primeFactors = primeFactors;

function primeFactors(num) {

    var res = [];
    var n = 2;
    while (num > 1) {
        while (num % n === 0) {
            res.push(n);
        }
        n++;
    }
    return res;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=numUtils-compiled.js.map
```

I have a script which requires the file

```
import {primeFactors} from "lib/numUtils";
```

It gets transpiled to

```
"use strict";

var _libNumUtils = require("lib/numUtils");

//# sourceMappingURL=ex3-compiled.js.map
```

When i run the script with nodejs i get

```
export function primeFactors(num) {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
     at require (module.js:384:17)
     at Object. (J:\webstorm_workspace\euler\ex3-compiled.js:3:20)
     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the transpiled script?

Comment: I run from the terminal "node ex3-compiled.js"

Comment: can you run the original with babel-node ?

Comment: When i run with babel-node i get the same result. I think i know the reason. My lib/numUtils.js file is compiled to lib/numUtils-compiled.js, but my original file stays untouched therefore i try to run es6 code with es5 interpretor. if i change to import {primeFactors} from "lib/numUtils-compiled"; it is solved. I am sure there is a better solution